# How can I create Azuredirectory sub directories with Lucene.net

Tags: c#, azure-storage, lucene.net

```
    CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("BlobStorage"));

    using (AzureDirectory azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(cloudStorageAccount, "Contents"))
    {
        IndexWriter indexWriter;
        try
        {
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), false,
                                  new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH));
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), true,
                                  new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH));

        }
```

this is my source.
I need create or using Sub Directory in my Container (Contents)

```
Contents/en/{filename}
Contents/ko/{filename}
Contents/jp/{filename}
```

How can I create AzureDirectory sub directory with Lucene.net

Comment: Is the "en", "ko", "jp" supposed to represent indexes with a certain analyzer?